Following Row Selection Example breaks checkboxes in Material React Table(v3)
Followed the example but once I update the line onRowSelectionChange: setRowSelection, the checkboxes do not get checked once I click on them.
Not sure if it's a re-render issue with the rowSelection not being passed back to the table properly.
This is pretty much exactly from the example but the checkboxes do not get checked when I click on them. But if I remove onRowSelectionChange: setRowSelection then the issue goes away.
type TableProps<T extends MRT_RowData> = {
  tablePropsObj: MRT_TableOptions<T>;
};

const Table = <T extends MRT_RowData>(props: TableProps<T>) => {
  const [pagination, setPagination] = useState({
    pageIndex: 0,
    pageSize: 10,
  });

  const [rowSelection, setRowSelection] = useState<MRT_RowSelectionState>({});
  
  const updatedTablePropsObj: MRT_TableOptions<T> = {
    enableColumnActions: false,
    enableRowSelection: true,
    enableSelectAll: true,
    enableTopToolbar: true,
    enableToolbarInternalActions: true,
    enableBottomToolbar: true,
    enablePagination: true,
    manualPagination: true,
    manualFiltering: true,
    positionPagination: 'bottom',
    onPaginationChange: setPagination,
    onRowSelectionChange: setRowSelection,
    ...props.tablePropsObj,
    state: {
      pagination,
      rowSelection,
    },
  }
  const table = useMaterialReactTable(updatedTablePropsObj);
  return (
    <>
      <MaterialReactTable table={table} />
    </>
  );
};


Looks like the issue I was having was from my passed down table props. I was using this table component as a child that other components can pass down to dependent on what I wanted to show.
From what I was able to find, the passed down propsTableObj was overwriting the onRowSelectionChange and RowSelection state.
type TableProps<T extends MRT_RowData> = {
  tablePropsObj: MRT_TableOptions<T>;
};

const Table = <T extends MRT_RowData>(props: TableProps<T>) => {
  const [pagination, setPagination] = useState({
    pageIndex: 0,
    pageSize: 10,
  });

  const [rowSelection, setRowSelection] = useState<MRT_RowSelectionState>({});
  
  const updatedTablePropsObj: MRT_TableOptions<T> = {
    enableColumnActions: false,
    enableRowSelection: true,
    enableSelectAll: true,
    enableTopToolbar: true,
    enableToolbarInternalActions: true,
    enableBottomToolbar: true,
    enablePagination: true,
    manualPagination: true,
    manualFiltering: true,
    positionPagination: 'bottom',
    ...props.tablePropsObj // Add this table props object here
    onPaginationChange: setPagination,
    onRowSelectionChange: setRowSelection,
    state: {
      pagination,
      rowSelection,
      ...props.tablePropsObj.state // add this to get the remaining state
    },
  }
  const table = useMaterialReactTable(updatedTablePropsObj);
  return (
    <>
      <MaterialReactTable table={table} />
    </>
  );
};

